# How to set secondary dns server with python

Tags: python, dns, wmi

I success set default DNS server with wmi like this

```
SetDNSServerSearchOrder([dns])
```

But I can't found how to set secondary DNS with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array of DNS server addresses. Try

```
SetDNSServerSearchOrder(['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4'])
```

The first is your primary, the second is your secondary